# How to emit event in router-outlet in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I have main appComponent with

```
<div class="appComponent">
<div class="row nav navbar">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left nav logo">Manacola</div>
    <button class="col-sm-1  col-sm-offset-1  btn btn-primary openGraph" (click)="openGraph()">Graph</button>
    <button class="col-sm-1   btn btn-primary openGraph" *ngIf="loggedIn" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</div>
<router-outlet ></router-outlet>
```

I would like to emit a data from another login component.
the point is that when I press "login" button in `loginComponent`, I want `*ngIf="loggedIn"` set 'true', in `appComponent`.
Would be good to have something like this working:

```
<router-outlet (isLogged) = 'loggedIn = $event' ></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can define an @Output event emitter in the component being rendered at router-outlet.
define router outlet as follows.

```
*.html
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

In your component you can do as so.

```
onActivate(elementRef) {
    elementRef.<the @Output eventEmitter>.subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
    });
}
```

This way you can send the events to the component which is rendering router-outlet. This works because @Output event emitters are event streams and you can subscribe to those events.

Comment: Hi Sorry, but what happen when you route to a Component that doesn't have that eventEmitter?

Comment: nice find. @ALGDB if your component doesn't have an Output, nothing is being emitted, right. You are just subscribing to events emitted to the RouterOutlet which is anything that emits up from a component used in the Outlet. You are kinda piggybacking on the activate event being emitted. Which is pretty clever.

Comment: Is this functionality specific to a version of Angular? This syntax is not working for me.

Comment: What does `(activate)` have to do with pressing the Log In button? `(activate)` is fired only when the route changes, isn't it?

Comment: @RonInbar, `(activate)` is triggered when route matched, so component's target is loaded (inside the <router-outlet>), and `(deactivate)` is triggered when route doesn't match anymore to the component target, you can modify the field `isLoggedIn` using those 2 events

Comment: yikes, careful with the angle brackets friends...they can do a number on ya...he he.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a great little utility service to broker events in an angular2 app.  Note that you should really only use this type of event broker to communicate between decoupled components (like between parents and children of router-outlet)

### Example:

```js
....
import { EventBrokerService, IEventListener } "EventBrokerService";

@Component({
    selector: "my-listening-component",
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="indicator">I am On!</div>
        <div *ngIf="!indicator">I am Off!</div>
    `
})
@Injectable()
export class MyListeningComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public indicator: boolean = false;
    private _myEventListener: IEventListener;
    constructor(private _eventBroker: EventBrokerService) {
        this._myEventListener = _eventBroker.listen<boolean>("my-event",(value:boolean)=>{
             this.indicator = value;
        });
    }
    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this._myEventListener.ignore();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-sending-component",
    template: `
        <button (click)="canYouHearMe(true)>Turn me on</Button>
        <button (click)="canYouHearMe(false)>Turn me off</Button>
    `
})
@Injectable()
export class MySendingComponent {
    constructor(private _eventBroker: EventBrokerService) {
    }
    public canYouHearMe(value:boolean) {
        _eventBroker.emit<boolean>("my-event",value);
    }
}
```

### The EventBrokerService.ts file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

interface IEventListener {
    ignore() : void;
}
interface IBrokeredEventBase {
    name:string;
    emit( data: any ): void;
    listen( next: (data: any) => void ): IEventListener;
}
interface IBrokeredEvent<T> extends IBrokeredEventBase  {
    emit( data: any ): void;
    listen( next: (data: any) => void ): IEventListener;
}
class EventListener implements IEventListener {
    constructor( private _subscription: Subscription ) {
    }
    public ignore() : void {
        this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}

class BrokeredEvent<T> implements IBrokeredEvent<T> {
    private _subject: Subject<T>;
    constructor( public name: string ) {
        this._subject = new Subject<T>();
    }
    public emit( data: T ): void {
        this._subject.next(data);
    }
    public listen(next: (value: T) => void): IEventListener {
        return new EventListener(this._subject.subscribe( next ));
    }
}
@Injectable()
export class EventBrokerService {
    private _events: { [name: string]: IBrokeredEventBase };
    constructor() {
        this._events = {};
    }
    public register<T>(eventName: string ) : BrokeredEvent<T> {
        var event = this._events[eventName];
        if ( typeof event === 'undefined' ) {
            event = this._events[eventName] = new BrokeredEvent<T>(eventName);
        }
        return event as BrokeredEvent<T>;
    }
    public listen<T>(eventName: string, next: (value: T) => void) : IEventListener {
        return this.register<T>(eventName).listen(next);
    }
    public emit<T>(eventName: string, data: T) : void {
        return this.register<T>(eventName).emit(data);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the EventBrokerService as a provider in your angular2 module.

Comment: `interface IEventListener` needs to be exported or else `MyListeningComponent` won't be able to see it

Comment: What is the purpose of IBrokeredEventBase to be extended by IBrokeredEvent, why is the second interface convenient?