# How to re-initialize parent component when navigating between child components?

Tags: angular

I am working on a complex project using `angular 15` with many routing, including lazy loading.

Say I have a parent component called `request.component.ts`, and it has child components like `step1.component.ts` and `step2.component.ts`

The parent `request` has some HTML code that is displayed commonly when child components are loaded, the data in the parent HTML changes based on the child component loaded.

When the child component `step1` is first loaded, the parent `request` is loaded as well, it loads some required data for this step to be displayed in the parent HTML. However, when I navigate to the second child `step2`, parent `request` isn't loaded again to fetch the required data I need, the data in the parent HTML are still based on the first child loaded not the second child as I expect.

I tried one solution which is subscribing to `router.events` of type `NavigationEnd` but after applying some business related logic and redirecting to a different parent route, the application gets into an infinite loop which I can tell by looking in the console log.

I would appreciate any simple workaround/solution as doing a major changes would not be convenient in my case (I have some deadlines from the higher up terrorizing me lol).

Comment: probably you can change the routing, in case if you have only two child components, please provide your routing file I am thinking about one workarround

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802714/6158032, in your main component can manage the (activate) and (desactivate) emitting events, when user reach the route and get out of the route.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.